# How to make quick menu items permanent in 2.8?

Tags: shortcut

When I add items to the quick menu in 2.8, they are lost every time I restart Blender. Any way to make them permanent?

Edit: in addition to the answer below, I discovered that the quick menu keys are different depending on which mode you're in (i.e., Object, Edit, etc...)

Comment: yes, i forgot to say that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to the edit->user preferences-> and click save(usually this button will be on bottom left.)
i think this will save the settings. so next time you open blender the settings will be loaded.
i hope it work...